# Get Dependecy Property from Binding expression

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dependency-properties, binding-expressions

I have a Binding expression object:

```
//e come from Validation.Error event
BindingExpression _bindingExpression = e.Error.BindingInError as BindingExpression;
```

I want to get the Dependecy Property.

For example, if the `bindingExpression` is a text of TextBox I want to get `TextBox.TextProperty`, etc..

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes from looking at the Documentation you can find a property on the [BindingExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.aspx) object called [TargetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase.targetproperty.aspx) which returns a DependencyProperty ( like TextBox.TextProperty).

Comment: You can give a specific line of code? because I can not find this object in Binding Expression.

Comment: @HodayaShalom, `var thePropertyYouWant = _bindingExpression.TargetProperty`, notice that `thePropertyYouWant` is a DependencyProperty and it is the one you are using in the binding like the TextProperty of a TextBox.

Comment: I get error : 'System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression' does not contain a definition for 'TargetProperty' and no extension method 'TargetProperty' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The TargetProperty Supported in: 4.5, I use 4.

Comment: @HodayaShalom, since you are using .NET 4 then i will have to ask for more information, what do you want the Dependency Property for, what is your final goal, what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @HodayaShalom, you can use Reflection i guess but it is a bit hard and painful.